# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: objective-c

I have this code that checks when a user is Verified to to complete Registration on the App:

```
-(void)handleVerify:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    __block BOOL foundError = false;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    transparentView.frame = self.view.frame;  //Provide frame of right side view.
    transparentView.alpha = 0.5;   //To provide transparent look and feel.
    transparentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:transparentView];

    //activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(transparentView.frame.size.width/2, transparentView.frame.size.height/2);
    [transparentView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    if(textfieldVerifyEmail.text.length > 0){
        labelErrorVerfiyEmail.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        foundError = true;
        labelErrorVerfiyEmail.hidden = NO;
    }

    if(textfieldVerifyNumber.text.length > 0){
        labelErrorVerifyNumber.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        foundError = true;
        labelErrorVerifyNumber.hidden = NO;
    }

    if(!foundError){
        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue2 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        // 3) Load picker in background
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue2, ^{
            NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&ver=%@", textfieldVerifyEmail.text,textfieldVerifyNumber.text];

            NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"checkUserVerification.php"];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(response.length > 0){
                    NSArray *items = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"|~|"];
                    NSString *ver =[items objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *idUser =[items objectAtIndex:1];
                    if([ver isEqualToString:@"verified"]){
                        textfieldVerifyNumber.text = @"";
                        textfieldVerifyEmail.text = @"";
                        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [transparentView removeFromSuperview];
                        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"REGISTERED" message:@"You are now Registered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil, nil];
                        [alert show];

                        userID = [idUser intValue];
                        [viewCreds removeFromSuperview];
                        [viewCredsRegister removeFromSuperview];
                        [viewCredsSignin removeFromSuperview];
                        [viewCredsVerify removeFromSuperview];

                        [self setupHeader];
                        [self setupNavigation];
                        [self setupFooter];
                        [self setupFooterNavigation];
                        [self switchView:7];
                        [self switchView:1];
                    }else{
                        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [transparentView removeFromSuperview];
                        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"VERIFICATION INVALID" message:@"Our records show that the Verification Number is incorrect, please try again or contact support@hugt.co.uk" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil, nil];
                        [alert show];
                    }
                }else{
                    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    [transparentView removeFromSuperview];
                    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SERVER ERROR" message:@"Server not Responding, please try back later..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
            });
        });
    }else{
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [transparentView removeFromSuperview];
        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But I get this error as soon as I click the verify button:

```
[1649:65950] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e2c746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x006a2a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d0dcb2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   InstantForum                        0x000944ab __31-[ViewController handleVerify:]_block_invoke_2 + 203
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x052fc5ea _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0531ebef _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x053046bb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 993
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00d858ee __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00d435f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 2256
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00d42a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00d4288b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x047682c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x04768106 GSEventRun + 104
    13  UIKit                               0x013ff0b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    14  InstantForum                        0x00112e9a main + 138
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x05349ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(Recorded Frame)
```

The Error occurs on this line of code:

> ```
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
> ```

Comment: How tall is your monitor?

Comment: Because you have so much whitespace in your code that one cannot possibly read it.

Comment: Fixed formatting.  My mother always told me I was a good person, and this proves it!  But that's some gnarly code.  I suggest you edit this question, replacing it with an MRE.

Comment: @danh A million thank yous (and some incoming upvotes) upon you.  (I was in the middle of making a similar edit too)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that ill remember next time

Comment: check the count of your `NSArray *items = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"|~|"];` before calling `-objectAtIndex`

Comment: As soon as you get this code working, I highly recommend you post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) where people will shorter monitors will help you learn how to organize your code better.

Comment: I think @0yeoj  has it right.  `someArray[0]` is dangerous unless you've concluded that `someArray.count > 0`

Comment: NO, its fine on my Xcode, i copied and pasted my code from xcode into text document to indent the code and paste it on SO but my bad, when i pasted the code in text document it made white spaces

Comment: Even without the white spaces, there's still way to much in this single method.  You need some refactoring.

Comment: I have added some code you suggested to check the count but still no luck

Comment: every variable beyond that error is nil, why?

Comment: @redoc01, because you might have failed to `componentsSeparatedByString` are you sure `@"|~|"` is in the string?

Comment: @0yeoj, yes you are correct, ill up vote you. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the count of your `NSArray *items = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"|~|"];` before calling `-objectAtIndex`.

You might have failed to `-componentsSeparatedByString`. Are you sure `@"|~|"` is in the string?